# RecyclerView --SelectionTracker limit selection size to 10 items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, limit, selection, max-size

I want to limit my RecyclerView `SelectionTracker` selection size to 10 items (max).

SelectionTracker init code:

```
val selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(
                        "my_selection_tracker_id",
                        myRecyclerView,
                        MyItemKeyProvider(),
                        MyItemLookup(myRecyclerView),
                        StorageStrategy.createParcelableStorage(MyItemModel::class.java)
                ).withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything())
                .build()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

After reading `SelectionTracker` documentation again, I found this one:

> In order to limit the number of items that can be selected,
>   use {@link #canSetStateForKey(Object, boolean)} and
>   {@link #canSetStateAtPosition(int, boolean)}.

So, I `override canSetStateForKey()` method from `SelectionPredicate` 

and add *if* condition which check item **nextState** (selected/deselected) and **selected items size**.

From documentation about canSetStateForKey():

> @return true if the item at {@code id} can be set to {@code nextState}

**Condition which limit selection size to 10:**

```
if(nextState && selectionTracker.selection.size() >= 10) {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

Full SelectionTracker initialization:

```
val selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(
                        "my_selection_tracker_id",
                        myRecyclerView,
                        MyItemKeyProvider(),
                        MyItemLookup(myRecyclerView),
                        StorageStrategy.createParcelableStorage(MyItemModel::class.java)
                ).withSelectionPredicate(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionPredicate<AttachmentMediaModel>() {
                    override fun canSelectMultiple(): Boolean {
                        return true
                   }
                   override fun canSetStateForKey(key: AttachmentMediaModel, nextState: Boolean): Boolean {
                       if(nextState && selectionTracker.selection.size() >= 10) { // 10 - max selection size
                           return false // Can't select when 10 items selected
                       }
                       return true // When selection size < 10 - allow selection
                   }
                   override fun canSetStateAtPosition(position: Int, nextState: Boolean): Boolean {
                       return true
                   }
               }).build()
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this but I changed it a bit where the tracker will unselect the oldest selection to "make room" for the new selection. Similar (mine is java and I'm only using a `long` key)

```
@Override
public boolean canSetStateForKey(@NonNull Long key, boolean nextState) {
    if (nextState && tracker.getSelection().size() >= MAX_SELECTIONS) {
        // Deselect the first selection and return true to allow the new item to be selected
        tracker.deselect(tracker.getSelection().iterator().next());
    }
    return true;
```

}